# what are the fastest java tools to generate CRUD screens from a DB schema?

Tags: java, data-binding, orm, crud

I am constantly in search of better and faster java tools to prototype webapps.  I generally start with a good data model on the backend, and work towards the screens.  What are some good tools that I might not know about that can be used to quickly generate functioning CRUD screens.

Comment: +1 because I miss Boston....:(

Comment: @hvgotcodes: +1 and +1 to your comment because I miss *"I miss Boston..."* comments :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look into the following:

- [Grails](http://www.grails.org/)
- [Play!](http://www.playframework.org/)
- [Roo](http://www.springsource.org/roo)

Answer (score 2):

With Grails you can get some CRUD screens in on the order of minutes with the framework's scaffolding machinery.  Its not strictly Java, but Grails can interact with existing Java code (in fact is uses Hibernate/Spring under the hood), and it will generate .war files for you to deploy in your favorite container.

Answer (score 2):

**Telosys Tools** is probably a response
It's an Eclipse plugin for scaffolding from an existing database
The templates can be customized if necessary
Let's have a look : https://sites.google.com/site/telosystools/

There are some stacks ready to use (Spring MVC, JPA, AngularJS, Spring Data, ... )
The tutorials are here : https://sites.google.com/site/telosystutorial/

Answer (score 1):

The Play Framework can generate some quick CRUD:

http://www.playframework.org/documentation/1.1RC3/guide7